# Background Thread to Call Methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, background-process

I've found this method to work with background thread. My question is that I've run a whole process in background thread which include number of methods. Frist method calls the second one and the the second one makes some data and pass it to the third one.

```
-(void)firstMethod
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

      if(someCondition == 0)
      {
        [self secondMethod:myArray];
      }
    }
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            });
    });
}
    -(void)secondMethod:(NSArray *)array {
       a= a+3;
       [self thirdMethod:array[a];
    }
```

So you get the general idea right? So do I have to put the functionality of second and third method in background thread too? Or how this whole process will take place?

Comment: All three method in you code will run in async mode (in background thread.) No need to create separate threads.

Comment: Both second and third method are going to be in Background thread only.

Comment: This depends on the time/space complexity of the work. If it is intensive and time expensive then it should be done on a background thread as otherwise it will block the main thread and cause lag and prevent the user from interacting with the interface.

Comment: Do I need to write them in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){` also or first one is enough for all?

Comment: @TalhaCh First one enough ..No need to write this code for other two methods.

Comment: @iOS_devloper if I need to `popViewController` should I do it in the new thread or main thread? As the send button is tapped and it is no longer need for user to stay in the screen while background process is running.