# Show UIActivityIndicatorView on a Specific Cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview

Here is the scenario:

- `OrderVC` have a table view on which if you right swipe it shows some
  options. In which one of the option is `Checkout`.
- When user taps on `Checkout` it opens up `CheckoutVC` which has a parent class `OrderVC`.
- Here user can add some text and can attach multiple images and can also save this data as draft which is achieved using core data. But when user submit the bill I'm using `AFNetworking` to call web api and upload images using `AFMultipartFormData`. All of this process is taking place on a background thread i.e.`dispatch_async`
- I can't update UI in `dispatch_get_main_queue` because methods are calling other method from within see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504453/background-thread-to-call-methods) it'll clear this point. So it calls the update UI right after first method is finished.

**Question**

As long as background thread is working it should show activity indicator on the cell. When it's finished and the response is success in `CheckoutVC` it should reload the tableView of `OrderVC`.

**Solution I tried**
I tried to run a `for` loop in `allOrderID` which are the ID's I get via web api hit of active orders. Then I made a call to `MR_findFirstByAttribute` to find if any of the fetched `OrderID` exist in drafts. There is an attribute `isSending` in `DraftOrderInfo` entity which is a BOOL and I truns it to true when checkout enters background thread. So if `isSending` is true I show the activity indicator in place of a UIView I created.

```
for (NSString *orderID in allOrderId) {
       DraftOrderInfo *dpi = [DraftOrderInfo MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"orderID" withValue:orderID];

       if (dpi.isSending) {
           orderCell.rightUtilityButtons = nil;

           activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
           activityView.center = CGPointMake(orderCell.orderStatusIndicatorBadgeView.frame.origin.x-2, orderCell.orderStatusIndicatorBadgeView.frame.origin.y-8);

           [activityView startAnimating];

           [orderCell.orderStatusIndicatorBadgeView addSubview:activityView];
       }
   }
```

The output I get is that when `OrderVC` is loaded it started showing activity indicator on all the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your following point is not valid. Read the comments on the question:

> can't update UI in dispatch_get_main_queue because methods are calling
>   other method from within see this question it'll clear this point. So
>   it calls the update UI right after first method is finished.

Back to the problem. There is multiple good practices to use. One of them:

1. Add the `UIActivityIndicator` to the `UITableViewCell` at design time(nib or storyboard) as done with the `UILabel`(s) and other controls.
2. On submitting the checkout. Change the isSending status to YES and inform the parent `UIViewController` to reload the table data by calling `reloadData` method on the `UITableView`.
3. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `willDisplay:forRowAt` method set the state of the activity indicator as animating or stopped based on the isSending value. This way even if reloading the table or scrolling up and down, the activity indicator will have its state right.
4. Whe the submitting finishes. Change the isSending state to YES and inform your parent ViewController to reload the table by calling `reloadData` method on the `UITableView`. And since the checkin finishes in a background thread you should inform your parent ViewController using `dispatch_get_main_queue`. read the comments on the question you added to your question. This point you mention regarding the `dispatch_get_main_queue` is wrong.

Comment: The isSending status is in core data and the cell data is being loading from the web. So is this a good way to use for loop to go through every cell and see if it's in core dta stack?

Comment: It depends. how many records do you have? I say if its about 1 to 2 Ks as max its ok.

Comment: But, when you display orders. are you storing them on a data structure or not?

Comment: I'm not sorting them in any order. The response object is stored in an array and then this array parse the data and display on cells. And no 1K or 2K is a huge number for this app you can say 30-50 entires per day.

Comment: Where do you have this loop? in which method?

Comment: in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127799/discussion-between-hasan83-and-talha-ch).